# Wrong value in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in using javaScript within  HTML, I am trying to create a multiplication between two values that entered by the user and display the result in another text box, but the result that displayed wrong.

There are three text box, the first box I put 2 and the second 7, in the third text box it should display the result is 14, but it show me the result is 98.

Could anybody help me?

My HTML code as the below:

```
<tr style="background:#fafafa;">
  <td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><textarea name="exp_desc" id="exp_desc" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea></td>
  <td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0; color: #D6D6D6;"><input class ="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
  <td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><input class ="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
  <td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><input span id='sum'  class ="txt" type="text" name="txt"></span></td>
  <td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><input type="file" name="datafile[]" size="40"></td>
</tr>
```

and the javaScript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 1;
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum *= parseFloat(this.value);
        } 
    });

    // enter code here 

    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your javascript to:

```
<script>
 var num1=0;
 var num2=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#txt1,#txt2").on("keyup",function(){
  num1  =   $("#txt1").val();
  num2  =   $("#txt2").val();
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
        num1 *= parseFloat(num2);
        $("#sum").val(num1.toFixed(2));
    }
});
}); 
</script>
```

Html:

```
<tr style="background:#fafafa;">
<td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><textarea name="exp_desc" id="exp_desc" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0; color: #D6D6D6;"><input class ="txt" type="text" name="txt" id="txt1"></td>
<td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><input class ="txt" type="text" name="txt" id="txt2"></td>
<td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><input  id='sum'  class ="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
<td style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;"><input type="file" name="datafile[]" size="40"></td>
</tr>
```